# Grails plugin controller not called from Grails application

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I created a Grails plugin "UserSecurity" and a controller "UserSecurityController" with index action and index.gsp page in /views/UserSecurity folder. I run the plugin and everthing works fine.
Then using below commands i created zip and then moved to local maven cache to use in other application.

```
grails package-plugin UserSecurity
grails maven-install
```

Now, i created a Grails application "UserApplication". Then created a controller "DefaultController" with index as action.

```
def index() {       
    redirect plugin:"user-security-plugin", controller:"Default", view:"index"
}
```

But the redirection is not working. When i run list-plugins it will list the UserSecurity plugin also.

Any idea how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `plugin` option of redirect is the camel case name, try:

```
redirect plugin:"userSecurity", controller:"default", view:"index"
```

Note also that the same rule is applied to the controller, so you need to start with lowercase.

Comment: No it is not working.When i run in firefox browser, i get the following message."The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies."

Comment: This is how i am calling in browser. http://localhost:8080/UserSecurityApplication/default/index